# Remote debugging problems

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I am trying to remote debug applications on a server in my local network.

**Server:**

```
$ uname -a 
Linux broatyctl.localdomain 3.6.11.2-rt33.39.el6rt.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Thu Jul 4 06:46:48 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gdbserver --version
GNU gdbserver (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6_4.1)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
gdbserver is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.
This gdbserver was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"
```

**Workstation:**

```
$ uname -a
Linux workstation.localdomain 3.12.7-300.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 10 15:35:31 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.6.50.20130731-16.fc20
```

I compiled a "Hello World" app on the workstation and it runs without errors on both workstation and server.

## This works on both server and workstation

**Shell 1:**

```
$gdbserver localhost:2345 CrossTest
```

**Shell 2:**

```
$ gdb CrossTest
(gdb)target extended-remote localhost:2345
(gdb)run
```

## This does not work

**Server:**

```
$ gdbserver workstation.ip.address:2345 CrossTest
```

**Workstation:**

```
$ gdb CrossTest
(gdb)target extended-remote server.ip.address:2345
(gdb)cont
```

**GDB output**

```
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f2a3b247d50 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

gdbserver tells me that there is an incomming connection, but it doesn't write my hello world message.

Any ideas?

*P.S. I allready posted this question on linuxquestions.org a while ago. I don't think that was the right forum, so I am trying my luck here.*

Comment: What version of gdbserver is running on the server?  [GDB 7.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/) introduced "Remote Protocol extensions" - possibly this includes the `extended-remote` command.  Can you use `target remote` instead?

Comment: Nope. Gdb caused a SIGSEGV. Otherwise the same: 0x00007f770bf26b00 in free@plt () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Comment: @DigitalTrauma That also caused a SIGSEGV. I updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling with -ggdb instead of -g AND using target remote instead of extended-remote did it.